# Easy way to take 1s clips from video every 60s and join them all together?

Tags: video, editing

Pretty much what the title says: I have a couple of video files and would like to extract one second intervals every sixty seconds or so, i.e. extract the clips

00:59 - 01:00
01:59 - 02:00
etc.

Then I would like to join all of these individual clips.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg, a command-line tool, can do this in one command.

**Update**: New template, first below, is easier to manipulate (and understand)

This is a generalized command template:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]select='gte(mod((t\-FS),I),0)*lt(mod((t\-FS),I),D)', setpts=N/TB/FRAME_RATE[v];  [0:a]aselect='gte(mod((t\-FS),I),0)*lt(mod((t\-FS),I),D)', asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```

Alternate method:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]select=isinf(t\/(mod(D*trunc(1+(t/D))\,Interval))),setpts=N/TB/FRAME_RATE[v];[0:a]aselect=isinf(t\/(mod(D*trunc(1+(t/D))\,Interval))),asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```

This is the first command formatted for full visibility

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]select='gte(mod((t\-FS),I),0)*lt(mod((t\-FS),I),D)', \
setpts=N/TB/FRAME_RATE[v]; \
[0:a]aselect='gte(mod((t\-FS),I),0)*lt(mod((t\-FS),I),D)', \
asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```

Basically, replace `input` with your source video filename, `output.mp4` with your intended output name.

Replace `D` with duration of segment, `I` for gap between the start of two segments and `FS` with start time of first segment . So, for 3-second segments every 45 seconds, starting at 36 seconds, from a file called `fullfile.mp4`, the command will be

```
ffmpeg -i fullfile.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]select='gte(mod((t\-36),45),0)*lt(mod((t\-36),45),3)', \
setpts=N/TB/FRAME_RATE[v]; \
[0:a]aselect='gte(mod((t\-36),45),0)*lt(mod((t\-36),45),3)', \
asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -fflags +genpts output.mp4
```

These segments will be extracts from seconds 36 to 39, 81 to 84..etc

Download ffmpeg for Windows (32-bit static build) from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: The joining part is easy compared to this. Just link to a concat question. Perhaps you should mention for OP that this method of cutting involves re-encoding. You could use `-ss` with `-c copy` to get slightly less accurate clips (depending on source codec) and avoid encoding.

Comment: In case, it's not clear, both commands both extract and join the segments into one clip. How will `ss` allow selection of all segments in one go?

Comment: I was thinking some kind of script, not all in one go. Also OP mentions he has several inputs, so he will probably need to run your command for each input and concat the results.